# Yocto useradd completes but no user added to /etc/passwd

Tags: yocto, yocto-recipe, yocto-kirkstone

I am trying to add a user to an inherited Yocto Kirkstone image build. I have added a recipe in

`<my-layer>/recipes-core/example-user/example-user.bb`

```
SUMMARY = "Add a nonroot user who has docker permissions"
LICENSE = "CLOSED"

inherit useradd
DEPENDS = "docker-ce"

USERADD_PACKAGES = "${PN}"
USERADD_PARAM:${PN} = "-u 1200 -s /bin/sh -G docker,dialout -m exampleuser"

BB_DONT_CACHE = "1"
```

In my `build/local.conf` I have:

```
IMAGE_INSTALL:append = " \
    example-user \
    docker \
    python3-docker-compose \
    eth0-static-ip \
    mount-or-fix-data-partition \
    run-startup-script \
"
```

I know that the recipe is being run because if I add `bogusgroup` to the list of groups in the `USERADD_PARAM:${PN}` line, bitbake fails with the expected group does not exist error. However, when I run the image and `cat /etc/passwd`, the user is not there.

@MikeBergmann asked if I checked `log.do_rootfs`. Indeed it looks like not all is well there, however I don't see an indication of what the actual problem was. Full output of the add users task:

```
NOTE: Executing systemd_create_users ...
DEBUG: Executing shell function systemd_create_users
configuration error - unknown item 'SYSLOG_SU_ENAB' (notify administrator)
configuration error - unknown item 'SYSLOG_SG_ENAB' (notify administrator)
Usage: useradd [options] LOGIN
       useradd -D
       useradd -D [options]

Options:
      --badnames                do not check for bad names
  -b, --base-dir BASE_DIR       base directory for the home directory of the
                                new account
      --btrfs-subvolume-home    use BTRFS subvolume for home directory
  -c, --comment COMMENT         GECOS field of the new account
  -d, --home-dir HOME_DIR       home directory of the new account
  -D, --defaults                print or change default useradd configuration
  -e, --expiredate EXPIRE_DATE  expiration date of the new account
  -f, --inactive INACTIVE       password inactivity period of the new account
  -g, --gid GROUP               name or ID of the primary group of the new
                                account
  -G, --groups GROUPS           list of supplementary groups of the new
                                account
  -h, --help                    display this help message and exit
  -k, --skel SKEL_DIR           use this alternative skeleton directory
  -K, --key KEY=VALUE           override /etc/login.defs defaults
  -l, --no-log-init             do not add the user to the lastlog and
                                faillog databases
  -m, --create-home             create the user's home directory
  -M, --no-create-home          do not create the user's home directory
  -N, --no-user-group           do not create a group with the same name as
                                the user
  -o, --non-unique              allow to create users with duplicate
                                (non-unique) UID
  -p, --password PASSWORD       encrypted password of the new account
  -r, --system                  create a system account
  -R, --root CHROOT_DIR         directory to chroot into
  -P, --prefix PREFIX_DIR       prefix directory where are located the /etc/* files
  -s, --shell SHELL             login shell of the new account
  -u, --uid UID                 user ID of the new account
  -U, --user-group              create a group with the same name as the user

groupadd: GID '65534' already exists
configuration error - unknown item 'SYSLOG_SU_ENAB' (notify administrator)
configuration error - unknown item 'SYSLOG_SG_ENAB' (notify administrator)
useradd: invalid user ID '65534:65534'
groupadd: group 'adm' already exists
configuration error - unknown item 'SYSLOG_SU_ENAB' (notify administrator)
configuration error - unknown item 'SYSLOG_SG_ENAB' (notify administrator)
groupadd: group 'utmp' already exists
groupadd: group 'audio' already exists
groupadd: group 'cdrom' already exists
groupadd: group 'dialout' already exists
groupadd: group 'disk' already exists
groupadd: group 'input' already exists
groupadd: group 'kmem' already exists
groupadd: group 'kvm' already exists
groupadd: group 'lp' already exists
groupadd: group 'render' already exists
configuration error - unknown item 'SYSLOG_SU_ENAB' (notify administrator)
configuration error - unknown item 'SYSLOG_SG_ENAB' (notify administrator)
groupadd: group 'tape' already exists
groupadd: group 'tty' already exists
groupadd: group 'video' already exists
groupadd: group 'users' already exists
configuration error - unknown item 'SYSLOG_SU_ENAB' (notify administrator)
configuration error - unknown item 'SYSLOG_SG_ENAB' (notify administrator)
useradd: user 'messagebus' already exists
groupadd: group 'systemd-journal' already exists
configuration error - unknown item 'SYSLOG_SU_ENAB' (notify administrator)
configuration error - unknown item 'SYSLOG_SG_ENAB' (notify administrator)
useradd: user 'systemd-network' already exists
configuration error - unknown item 'SYSLOG_SU_ENAB' (notify administrator)
configuration error - unknown item 'SYSLOG_SG_ENAB' (notify administrator)
useradd: user 'systemd-resolve' already exists
configuration error - unknown item 'SYSLOG_SU_ENAB' (notify administrator)
configuration error - unknown item 'SYSLOG_SG_ENAB' (notify administrator)
useradd: user 'systemd-timesync' already exists
DEBUG: Shell function systemd_create_users finished
```

EDIT 2024-03-11

Looking further into the `SYSLOG_SU_ENAB` message, it appears to be from the [shadow](https://github.com/shadow-maint/shadow/blob/d2f2c1877a30849912e1f3490a21808fa87fcd4c/etc/login.defs#L70) recipe. It doesn't look like it would cause a command failure, just interfere with logging.

```
#
# Enable "syslog" logging of su(1) activity - in addition to sulog file logging.
# SYSLOG_SG_ENAB does the same for newgrp(1) and sg(1).
#
SYSLOG_SU_ENAB      yes
SYSLOG_SG_ENAB      yes
```

Further edit, 2024-03-11:
I have also confirmed that the error above occurs even when my recipe is not present.

Looking further, it appears that during the build process, the recipe is turned into a series of do_ scripts in the directory

`/home/jenkins/oe-core/build/tmp/work/cortexa72-cortexa53-tdx-linux/example-user/1.0-r0/recipe-sysroot/temp/` of which the relevant script is

`/home/jenkins/oe-core/build/tmp/work/cortexa72-cortexa53-tdx-linux/example-user/1.0-r0/temp/run.useradd_sysroot.3752244`

This contains the following bash function:

```
# line: 30, file: /home/jenkins/oe-core/build/../layers/openembedded-core/meta/classes/useradd_base.bbclass
perform_useradd() {
        local rootdir="$1"
        local opts="$2"
        bbnote "example-user: Performing useradd with [$opts]"
        local username=`echo "$opts" | awk '{ print $NF }'`
        local user_exists="`grep "^$username:" $rootdir/etc/passwd || true`"
        if test "x$user_exists" = "x"; then
                eval flock -x $rootdir/etc -c  \"$PSEUDO useradd \$opts\" || true
                user_exists="`grep "^$username:" $rootdir/etc/passwd || true`"
                if test "x$user_exists" = "x"; then
                        bbfatal "example-user: useradd command did not succeed."
                fi
        else
                bbnote "example-user: user $username already exists, not re-creating it"
        fi
}
```

This function determines success by grepping a /etc/passwd file and making sure that the username is present. However the /etc/passwd file appears to be local to the recipe directory:

`/home/jenkins/oe-core/build/tmp/work/cortexa72-cortexa53-tdx-linux/example-user/1.0-r0/recipe-sysroot/etc/passwd`

When the build completes this `etc/passwd` file no longer exists.

Comment: Did you check your log.do_rootfs? Every useradd and groupadd is listed there with potential error messages. You will find it in your image folder beneath the build folder.

Comment: Good question! updated with the output

Comment: @ruffle same error as in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73801394/yocto-kirkstone-systemd-create-users-issue-on-first-build) question, do you add multiple users maybe?

Comment: The layer that I'm maintaining is not adding users. I'm noticing that many of the openembedded layers add users (meta-networking, meta-webserver, meta-perl, meta-oe, recipes-connectivity, etc). I don't see how it's plausible that these things are causing the problem because a) they are pretty foundational and it is unlikely that this would work for any project if they break it b) these do not interfere with each other.

However I also see some changes to useradd in an selinux recipe, where I would say probably all bets are off.

Comment: Further: removing the SElinux layer results in no change.